# How to trigger onchange event in an IFrame mithril element when a codemirror editor in the srcdoc of the IFrame changes?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, codemirror, mithril.js

Let's say I have a HTML called `post.html` that has a `codemirror` editor in it. the `post.html` looks something like:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.29.0/codemirror.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.29.0/codemirror.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.59.3/mode/python/python.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea id="editor">Hello World</textarea>
    </body>

<script>
window.onload = function () {
    var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea($("#editor")[0], {
        lineNumbers: true,
        lineWrapping: false,
    });

    editor.on('change', (editor) => {
        window.postMessage({'data': 'some data'}, '*')
        // somehow trigger the IFrames onchange event??
    });

}
</script>
</html>
```

I have a `mithril` IFrame element. The snippet for this looks something like

```
mithrilIFrame = {
    oncreate: function(vnode) {
        vnode.dom.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
              console.log("event found in listen!", event);
            });
    },

    view: function(vnode) {
        data.src = "post.html";
        data.onchange = myFunc;

        return m("iframe", data);
    }
};

myFunc = function(){
    // get the text from the codemirror editor and do something with it
}
```

Now, whenever new text is entered in the codemirror editor, I would like to trigger the `onchange` event in my mithril IFrame element that would grab the text in the codemirror editor and do something with this text. I know how to grab the text from the codemirror editor in the `onchange` event. But I cant figure out how to trigger the IFrame's `onchange` event every time something is changed in the editor.

The `addEventListener` in my mithril dom, does not seem to listen to the `postMessage` in triggered from the editors `onchange`. (I also tried `window.parent.postMessage` it did not help either).

Please help. I'm clueless. Also I'm no expert in `js`, `jquery`, or `mithril`, so please pardon any very stupid mistakes I might have made

Answer (score 1):

The code in the `script` tags seem to be giving a `SyntaxError`, the error states `SyntaxError: expected property name, got '{'` this is because your `Window.onload` function has two opening brackets, and your `CodeMirror.fromTextArea` object, once again, has two opening brackets. The error was the reason why you can't trigger the `onchange` event every time you change something in the editor.

**The code in the script tag should look like this**

```js
window.onload = windowLoad;

function () {
  var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea($("#editor")[0],{
  lineNumbers: true,
  lineWrapping: false,
  });

  editor.on('change', (editor) => {
    window.postMessage({'data': 'some data'}, '*')
  });
}
```

Now every time something changes `window.postMessage` gets called

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the error. But unfortunately its just a typo. I have updated my question. It still does not trigger the onchange event. :(